# HTML tag encoder

Tags: php, html

**library.php**

My own HTML tag encoder that will print HTML codes according to the input.

```
<?php
    function tag($tagname, $content = NULL, array $properties = NULL)
    {
        $html = "<$tagname";

        if (!($properties === NULL))
        foreach ($properties as $name => $value) {
            $html .= " $name=\"$value\"";
        }

        $html .= ($content === NULL || $content == "") ? " />" : ">$content</$tagname>";

        return $html;
    }
?>
```

**index.php**

The test index.php file that will run the HTML encoder from the library.

```
<?php 
    require 'library.php';

    echo tag("head",
        tag("meta","",array("name"=>"title","content"=>"Test Print"))
    );
    echo tag("body",
        tag("div",tag("p","test print".tag("br")."test print"),array())
    );
?>
```

**Output:**

```
<head><meta name="title" content="Test Print" /></head><body><div><p>test print<br />test print</p></div></body>
```

**Question:**

Using this library will make my code more readable when adding more PHP code. Instead of this `<div><?php $variable ?></div>`, I can use this `echo tag("div",$variable);`, but the latter will definitely be longer compared to just typing HTML code.

Should I not create such function and stay with coding HTML?

Comment: You think that is *more* readable? CGI.pm did that decades ago and I've been running screaming from it ever since.

Comment: This is an opinionated topic. I wouldn't suggest taking that route (or reinventing the wheel).

Comment: Ditch this, get a decent ide and practice pcode formatting instead

Comment: Using XMLWriter we can write this structure without too much trouble.

Comment: This is very musch an opinion question, but I would say yes! Under _some_ _circumstances_ it can be a very good idea. Like if you maintain a little CMS. In some projects I have a huge static HTML class. Then I call for example `HTML::br(3)` to draw 3 `<br>`'s, or like you - `HTML::div($content, $class)`. This can be easier to have a "scaffold" to echo out the HTML with, and it is a whole lot easier to change behaviour of certain parts of the HTML later on.

Comment: Thanks to all!
@davidkonrad I'll think about your way
dvdyakonov thanks for XMLWriter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but echo is not the right tool for the job IMO.

Thinking about XML generally we can represent the data like this:

```
array('tag', $attributes, $children);
```

The nesting of child elements allows us to do this (children is either an array for a nested element, or a string for a simple text child).

```
array('div',
      array('class' => 'container'),
      array(array('span', array(), 'One'),
            array('span', array(), 'Two')));
```

Which represents:

```
<div class="container">
    <span>One</span>
    <span>Two</span>
</div>
```

Using [XMLWriter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) we can write this structure without too much trouble. Look at [this](https://github.com/Evoke-PHP/Evoke-PHP/blob/master/src/php/Evoke/Writer/XML.php) library. The output from XMLWriter is always indented correctly, regardless of the context a template should appear in.

This is a classic example of matching your data structure to the problem you are solving. By creating a tree to represent the X(HT)ML we can build components of the structure where they belong in our code, rather than being forced to get all of our echo statements in the correct order.